# hosting expressjs api in NGNIX

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nginx

I'm struggling with hosting my expressjs api on NGINX using a DockerFile.

This is my DockerFile

```
FROM node:13.2.0-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_ENV = production

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./bin ./bin
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./index.js .

#production environment
FROM node:13.2.0-alpine as production
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

this deploys the container, but I can ping it because the application is not started. at the moment it works without the web server using this command `CMD ["npm", "start"]`

How do I start the nginx sever and the node service at the same time?

This is my node:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./bin/www",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

ngnix config:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;   
    gzip on;
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is typically done with two separate containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do goes against the idea of containerisation. If you really want to run both `express` (api) and `nginx` (proxy) in a single container, you could try creating bash script which would run both and serve it as `ENTRYPOINT` in your `Dockerfile`. (see Andrei's answer)

However this is not what I would recommend you doing. Instead it would be better to run them in separate containers (e.g via `docker-compose` to test it locally) and allow them to communicate over network. This will require you to split your `Dockerfile` to two separate configurations.

API

```
FROM node:13.2.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_ENV = production

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./bin ./bin
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./index.js .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Proxy

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

That way you can run them as two containers, where `nginx` would be exposing port 80 and `express` exposing port 3000. Even better solution would be to create `docker-compose` configuration and automate a lot of this code (where you wouldn't need to create a separate nginx docker image, just use standard one with mounted volume). On how to do that please consult the [docker compose docks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file for example `start_services.sh` and execute it with docker `CDM`. file content example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd your-directory
nginx && npm run start
```

in this case two services will be up and running from one single docker container.